# How to restrict user from entering numbers or special characters in to text input field in react class components

Tags: html, reactjs

im trying to restric user from entering numbers using regex in to my text type input . how can i achieve it ,

```
  nameChangeHandler=(e)=>{
    const userInput={...this.state.userInput};
    const reg=/[0-9]/;
    if(reg.test(e.currentTarget.value))
    e.preventDefault();
    userInput[e.currentTarget.name]=e.currentTarget.value
    this.setState({
      userInput
    })
  }
 <input id="nameInput"  type="text" name="username" value={username} onChange={this.nameChangeHandler} />
```

This is what i have tried doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex pattern to "not allow" for numbers (= check whether numbers are not in the string): `/^([^0-9]*)$/`

Example regex to additionally check for special characters ($ and %):
`/^([^0-9$%]*)$/`

Assuming your current handler works, this should prevent users from typing a number and % and $:

```
nameChangeHandler=(e)=>{
    const reg=/^([^0-9$%]*)$/;
    if (reg.test(e.currentTarget.value)) {
      this.setState({ ...this.state.userInput, username: e.currentTarget.value })
    }
  }
```

Comment: How can i add special characters to this regex

Comment: https://regex101.com will help and educate you. But for example, to exclude $ and %, too: `/^([^0-9$%]*)$/`